# How to use client ipv6 /ipv4 ip address with server ipv6 address.?

Tags: python, sockets, server, serversocket

When I am trying to run my server with '::' then my connection with client ipv6 and ipv4 got connected but if I put the ipv6 address IP in replace of '::' then Ipv4 client connection got refused.

```
# Function to perform Non-secured Connection.
def establishNonSecureConnection(self):
    tcpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    addr = [addr for addr in socket.getaddrinfo('::', 2010, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM,0, socket.AI_PASSIVE)]
    try:
        tcpServer.bind(addr[0][-1])
    except socket.error as e:
        print str(e)
    tcpServer.listen(4)
    while True:
        (conn, (ip, port, a , b)) =  tcpServer.accept()
        print("Client connected: {}:{}".format(ip, port))
```

Is there anything is missing from my side here?

Comment: No, that’s how it works. If you put a specific address then that’s the only one you’re listening on. What would be the IPv4 address you could use if you only listen on an IPv6 address?

Comment: What is the point of calling `getaddrinfo` to get an IP address the server will listen at? The address is known, isn't it?

Comment: @VPfB Yes address is already known, I just want that if somebody wants to run the server on another machine then they can add the machine IP address to run the server.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen ok

Comment: @DeepakMourya There are usually three options to specify the listening address: 1) all available addresses for "public" network services (access may be controlled by a packet filtering firewall), 2) loopback only for "host local" services, 3) address specified by the admin for fine-tuning access on a server with more that one real network interface. In case 1 and 2 the addresses are well known and in case 3 `getaddrinfo` won't help.